# Flex - Download asset to local

Tags: apache-flex, download, local, assets

I've got an interactive presentation, and it's all working as it should.
Now I want to add a function to download the currently visible image/video.

Because this presentation has a lot of files (all stored under assets/...) and it's a pain to navigate through the assets, I want an easy way to just click a button and get a "Save as.." window.

I've managed to get the url of the media, so now I just need a way to show a "save as.." dialog to allow the users to save/download the file and save it locally.

This whole presentation should be put online, so all the files are located somewhere in the /assets/.. folder inside the project.

Any ideas of how to do this? =)

Thanks!

EDIT #1:
For now I'm using "navigateToURL" to open a new browser window with the media. This works, but is there a way to show a "Save as.." dialog instead of opening the image?

Or any other ways to do this? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class, in particular the `FileReference.save( data:*,defaultFileName:String = null )` method. That will open up a "Save..." dialog to save the corresponding data object and allow you to set a default file name. I'm unsure if this class can also handle the download as I have never had a time when I needed to prompt to save something that was to be downloaded. If it cannot handle it, you'll need to look into the [URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) class. That can handle the download and either on ProgressEvent.PROGRESS or Event.COMPLETE, you simply do a `URLStream.readBytes( byteArray );` to save the downloaded bytes to a ByteArray and then that is the data object you save. I would look into the FileReference class, though. Odds are it can handle downloads as well.